# Optimizing a sumif-like query in R

Tags: r, sumifs

I have a dataframe with 1.8 million rows, and each row contains one or more of a selection of 30,000 tags. I'm trying to find how many rows contain an instance of each tag. Some items contain as many as 25 tags, each of which is in its own column. No row contains more than one instance of any tag:

```
ItemNo <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)  
Tag1 <- c("ZZZ", "AAA", "BBB", "YYY")  
Tag2 <- c("YYY2", "ZZZ", "AAA", "XXX")  
Tag3 <- c("", "YYY2", "AAA2", "XXX3")  
Tag4 <- c("", "", "", "AAA")  
Tag5 <- c("", "", "", "ZZZ")  
Tag6 <- c("", "", "", "YYY2")  
Items <- data.frame(ItemNo, Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4, Tag5, Tag6)  
Items

  ItemNo Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 Tag4 Tag5 Tag6
1      1  ZZZ YYY2       
2      2  AAA  ZZZ YYY2   
3      3  BBB  AAA AAA2   
4      4  YYY  XXX XXX3  AAA  ZZZ YYY2
```

The universe of tags is in a separate data set:

```
Code <- c("AAA", "BBB", "XXX", "ZZZ", "AAAA", "XXX3", "YYY2")  
COUNT <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  
tags <- data.frame(Code, COUNT) 
tags 

  Code COUNT  
1  AAA     0  
2  BBB     0  
3  XXX     0  
4  ZZZ     0  
5 AAAA     0  
6 XXX3     0  
7 YYY2     0
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
   Code COUNT  
1  AAA     3  
2  BBB     1  
3  XXX     1  
4  ZZZ     3  
5 AAAA     0  
6 XXX3     1  
7 YYY2     3
```

I'm able to get good results with a for loop, which takes about 3 hours to run through the dataset:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(tags)) {tags[i,2] <- sum(Items[,2:7] ==
as.character(tags[i,1]), na.rm = TRUE)}
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant way to count the instances of each tag in this data set?

Comment: `table(unlist(tags[-1]))`. And convert all your columns to `character` *before* running the loop. (or anything else). Best do to that when the data frame is created (`stringsAsFactors = F`). Just moving `as.character()` outside of the loop will probably shave 30 minutes off of your 3-hour run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make an example at something close to your scale:

```
n = 1e6
ncol = 25
ItemNo <- 1:n
tags = c("", do.call(paste0, expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
item_tags = sample(tags, size = n * ncol, replace = T)

Items <- cbind.data.frame(ItemNo, matrix(item_tags, ncol = ncol))
```

The above has 25 tag columns, 1 million rows, with 26^3 + 1 = 17577 unique tags.

```
system.time(table(unlist(Items[-1])))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 15.077   1.001  16.277
```

Running `table` on everything but the first column, unlisted, takes about 15 seconds on my laptop. The output should be usable:

```
tt = table(unlist(Items[-1]))
head(tt)
#       AAA  AAB  AAC  AAD  AAE 
# 1421 1451 1456 1479 1440 1449
```

Convert to data frame to match your desired output:

```
dd = data.frame(tt)
head(dd)
#   Var1 Freq
# 1      1421
# 2  AAA 1451
# 3  AAB 1456
# 4  AAC 1479
# 5  AAD 1440
# 6  AAE 1449
```

Note that it also counts the blanks - you might want to subset those out post-hoc.

---

**Edit:** For more speed, you can use `tabulate` rather than `table`. `table` has options that we don't need in this case - `tabulate` is a stripped-down version. Using `tabulate` instead of `table` runs in under 10 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Using table/unlist got the run time from 2 hours 55 minutes down to 9 seconds. Tremendous, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the speed on your large data set, but I'm guessing this would be faster, as it uses `apply` instead of a `for` loop:

```
Sums <- data.frame(Code = Code,
                   COUNT = unlist(lapply(Code, function(i)
                             sum(apply(Items, 1, function(x) any(i %in% x))))))
```

Working out from the center of the `COUNT =` line, this approach:

- Uses `apply` along the rows to get a logical indicating whether or not a given item in the vector of possible codes appears in that row.
- Wraps that call to `apply` in a call to `lapply` that applies that process to each item in the vector of codes (`Codes`) and sums the results.
- Unlists the resulting list so it becomes a vector.
- Puts that vector in a data frame alongside a column showing the relevant codes.

Result:

```
> Sums
  Code COUNT
1  AAA     3
2  BBB     1
3  XXX     1
4  ZZZ     3
5 AAAA     0
6 XXX3     1
7 YYY2     3
```

Comment: This is more elegant than my for loop. Interestingly it actually increased the runtime by about three-fold from my original. I can't think why that would be. One reason might be that I'm reading from the column in 'tags' rather than the original array
This method has the added benefit of restoring the original order of 'tags'.

Comment: Well, clearly my approach does not help. Sorry. I would delete the answer, but I think it could be informative, so I'll leave it up.